# VB.NET - Checkbox disabled while doing postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, postback

I have a checkbox with autopostback.  This checkbox will either hide/show a column in my datagrid.  I want my checkbox disabled/read only while the post back is occurring, to avoid double clicking or server errors.  I understand disabling the check box will not hold the value through the postback.  From what I've read in other similar questions, I need to create a hidden input and assign that the value of my checkbox.  How I have it right now, hidden input always has a value of false after postback.  Any advice/help would be appreciated.

*Only showing relevant code.

ASPX:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxEmailPhone" runat="server" Text="Include Telephone & E-Mail" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="bold tdfont10" value="<%=hidPhoneEmail%>" name="EmailPhoneCheck"></asp:CheckBox>

<input type="hidden" id="hidChkBxValue" value=" <%=hidPhoneEmail%>" name="EmailPhoneCheck"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function fnDisableChkBox(){
    if(document.getElementById("chkbxEmailPhone").checked = true){
        document.getElementById("hidChkBxValue").value = "true";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("hidChkBxValue").value = "false";
    }

    document.getElementById("chkbxEmailPhone").disabled = true;
}
```

VB.NET: In Page_PreRender

```
'Declared normally - not in prerender
Public hidPhoneEmail As String = String.Empty 

chkbxEmailPhone.Attributes.Add("onChange", "fnDisableChkBox(this);")

hidPhoneEmail = Request.Form("hidPhoneEmail")

If hidPhoneEmail = "true" Then
    chkbxEmailPhone.Checked = True
Else
    chkbxEmailPhone.Checked = False
End If
```

Comment: I should note that without disabling the check box, the page works exactly how it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a [HiddenField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx) control since it is easy to obtain its value on the PostBack.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxEmailPhone" runat="server" Text="Include Telephone & E-Mail" AutoPostBack="true" value="<%=hidChkBxValue%>" name="EmailPhoneCheck"></asp:CheckBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidChkBxValue" runat="server" Value="" />
```

Then your PreRender Event Handler becomes the following.  You shouldn't need the third hidden value "hidPhoneEmail", so just replace hidChkBxValue.Value = "false" with however you are determining the value in the first place.

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    chkbxEmailPhone.Attributes.Add("onChange", "fnDisableChkBox(this);")

    If hidChkBxValue.Value = String.Empty Then
        'How do you figure out the original value?
        hidChkBxValue.Value = "false"
    End If

    chkbxEmailPhone.Checked = CBool(hidChkBxValue.Value)
End Sub
```

Your JavaScript function should be fine so long as ASP.net isn't changing IDs on you.

Comment: I cannot see where this answer disables the checkbox during postback.

Comment: No code change should be required there.  At worst just getting the ClientID of the HiddenField.

Comment: This way retains the hidden value after the post back, but the checkbox does not stay checked.

Comment: Darren S - My original javascript disables the checkbox, along with assigning the hidden field a value.  That part of the code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

NoAlias - I used your suggested changes, so my code looks as below.

This works great the first time I click the checkbox, from unchecked to checked.  After that, when I try to uncheck the box, the value of chkbxEmailPhone.Checked turns False, but the hiddenfield remains true through the post back, and in pre_render the checkbox is switched back to chkbxEmailPhone.Checked = True.

I believe the problem is with my javascript, because the hiddenfield remains true after the first post back, no matter what.  Javascript is not my strong suit so I am unsure of a fix.

ASPX:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkbxEmailPhone" runat="server" Text="Include Telephone & E-Mail" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="bold tdfont10" Value=""></asp:CheckBox>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hidChkBxValue" runat="server" Value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
function fnDisableChkBox(){

    if(document.getElementById("chkbxEmailPhone").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("hidChkBxValue").value = "true";
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById("hidChkBxValue").value = "false";
        }

   document.getElementById("chkbxEmailPhone").disabled = true;
    }
```

VB.Net - Pre_Render

```
chkbxEmailPhone.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return buttonClick(this);")

If hidChkBxValue.Value = String.Empty Then
    hidChkBxValue.Value = "false"
End If
chkbxEmailPhone.Checked = CBool(hidChkBxValue.Value)
```

Comment: Now I feel dumb.  Just remembered Javascripts compare operator is ==, not =.  Works like a charm with that change. Edited code above with change, in case anyone else needs a working example.  Thanks NoAlias.